# django, google app engine and google drive api

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a simple django project (website) that authenticates the user using OAuth2 and returns a list of files from my google drive account using the drive api v2.

the problem is that I can't get the authentication working, the exception is:

> 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'redirect'

if someone has managed to get some application going using django mtv file structure get give me some references or a sample project please reply

The sample application can be accessed at: http://helloworldbyionut.appspot.com/home/

Comment: You should post the full stack trace of the the exception and the source of your own file where the exception occurs

Comment: Access the application at http://helloworldbyionut.appspot.com/home/ and then click the second link 'add article' there you can see the error. I think the error ocurred when setting the WSGIHandler like this 'application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()' and i think it should be like 'application = webapp2.WSGIHandler(...)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use app engine, easiest way to do oauth is to use [oauth_required](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine) decorator. It does all the Oauth2 steps automatically.